# Error message being thrown: Index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, junit, indexoutofboundsexception

For the following code I am getting an index out of bounds exception and I am not sure as to why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public Rabbit nearestRabbit()
{
    List<Rabbit> rabbits = this.getWorld().getObjects(Rabbit.class);
    if (this.getWorld().getObjects(Rabbit.class) == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    Rabbit nearest = rabbits.get(0);
    double distance = distanceTo(nearest);

    for (Rabbit rabbit : rabbits)
    {
        double thisDistance = distanceTo(rabbit);
        if (thisDistance > distance)
        {
            distance = thisDistance;
            nearest = rabbit;
        }
    }
    return nearest; //@@@@@@@
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? From `rabbits.get(0)`?

Comment: yes at Rabbit nearest = rabbits.get(0)

Comment: your if statement should be `rabbits == null || rabbits.isEmpty()` instead of `this.getWorld().getObjects(Rabbit.class) == null`

Answer (score 4):

This is mainly due to your list size, I know that you have checked null for the list but since the list is not `null` it can still be empty with the size `0` and you can not access to the element at index `0`.
I recommend you to check the list size.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this exception by not checking if the index is in bounds in the call `rabbits.get(0)`.

A simple workaround is to put this code first.

```
if (rabbits.isEmpty())
    return null;
```

This checks if the list is empty before making any other calls.

Also, it would be best to refrain from reference `this.getWorld().getObjects(Rabbit.class)` more than once, especially after holding it as a variable which is much more accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Add a size check to your if

```
if (this.getWorld().getObjects(Rabbit.class) == null || rabbits.isEmpty() )
```

A list may well not be null yet still be empty. E.g. any freshly generated one:

```
LinkedList<Object> objs = new LinkedList<>();
System.out.println(objs != null && objs.isEmpty()); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IndexOutOfBound is probably when you are getting element at index 0 where the list might be empty.

```
if (!rabbits.isEmpty())
{
    Rabbit nearest = rabbits.get(0);
}
```